# Accessing the body of a request

Tags: javascript, express

```js
const app = express()
app.use(bodyParser())



router.get('/edaman', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body)
  axios.get(edamanUrl)
    .then(function (response) {
      const recipes = response.data.hits
      return res.status(200).json({ body: recipes })
    })
})
```

I'm trying to access the keys within recipe, within the body....However, the console.log(req.body)
gives me back this. When I do req.body.recipe I get back undefined....I'm clearly missing something obvious and stupid to get within that object.
Thank you in advanced.

{ '{\n    "recipe": {\n      "ingredient": "chicken"\n    }\n  }': '' }

Comment: It looks like you have a nested object in your body, which is why it's not finding the `recipes` property. What does your `recipes` object look like?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have installed `bodyParser` and required it. I would suggest to use `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))`
`app.use(bodyParser.json())`.